# Is $x$ raised to the power of $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ equal to $\begin{bmatrix}x^a&x^b-1\\x^c-1&x^d\end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, wolfram-alpha

WolframAlpha says $x$ raised to the power of $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ is equal to $\begin{bmatrix}x^a&x^b\\x^c&x^d\end{bmatrix}$.

$x = e^{\ln x}$ , and ${x^a}^b = x^{a \cdot b}$
$\therefore$ $x^M = e^{\ln x \cdot M}$ , where $M$ is a matrix.

According to 3Blue1Brown, $e^{y \cdot M} = y^0 \cdot M^0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{y^n}{n!} \cdot M^n \right)$

But when I asked to [Mathics](https://mathics.org/) (open source alternative to Mathematica) the result of the sum above, it said it's $\begin{bmatrix}x^a&x^b-1\\x^c-1&x^d\end{bmatrix}$

Which one is wrong?

---

If anyone want to know what I typed in Mathics:

```
IdentityMatrix[2] + Sum[((Log[x]^n/n!) * {{a,b},{c,d}}^n), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

*(in Mathics `Log[x]` is $\ln x$)*

Comment: What did you type in Wolfram?

Comment: It looks like both are doing elementwise exponentiation rather than a proper exponential. The second one is different because you expicitly split off the $n = 0$ term and made it $I$ by fiat.

Comment: In particular, the examples at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixExp.html very clearly differ from what one would get by plugging $x=e$ into the formulas you gice.

Comment: Incidentally there is not a simple formula for the exponential of a 2 x 2 matrix. The best you can get is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Evaluation_by_Laurent_series

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mathematica and all things pretending to be Mathematica, `x^{{a,b},{c,d}}` and `{{a,b},{c,d}}^x` don't know that you're dealing with a matrix, and are going to apply the operation elementwise.

You want `MatrixPower[{{a,b},{c,d}},n]` to raise a matrix to the $n^{\text{th}}$ power, and `MatrixFunction[x^#&, {{a,b},{c,d}}]` or `MatrixExp[Log[x]{{a,b},{c,d}}]` for the matrix exponential with the weird base.

Comment: Thanks, I thought both were wrong too, because $\cos -1 \ne e^{-1}$